# Rather high CPU usage with memory monitoring bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I wrote a little script to monitor memory usage and send an e-mail when free cached memory drops below 1000 MB, but is greater than 800 MB:

```
#!/bin/bash
while [ true ] ;do
used=`free -m |awk 'NR==3 {print $4}'`

if [ $used -lt 1000 ] && [ $used -gt 800 ]; then
echo "Free memory is below 1000MB. Possible memory leak!!!" | /bin/mail -s "HIGH MEMORY ALERT!!!" user@mydomain.com

sleep 5
fi
done
```

The script works very well but, for some reason, it has a 10% constant CPU usage (and we are talking about a new generation quad-core Xeon processor. I have much bigger scripts that stay well below 1% CPU usage.

Any idea what's causing this and how I can optimize it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Any idea what's causing this and how I can optimize it?

The line

```
sleep 5
```

is inside the condition that checks whether the memory is within the specified range.  Chances are that most of the times that memory isn't within this range, which causes the infinite loop *without any sleep* whatsoever and makes the script consume more resources than you'd expect it to.

Take the line outside the `if` loop and that should help.

Comment: Ah, damn! How could I miss this? You are right. CPU usage dropped to ~0%

Answer (score 0):

Run it via cron instead of an infinite loop, and see if that helps.

Comment: The minimum timeframe for Cron is 1 minute. There is no way to cron a script every 5 seconds.